# Relativistic effects real?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, relativity, inertial-frames, observers

Are relativistic effects physically real or just apparent due to limited speed of information? Does metal rod really contract in length or do we just "see" it that way due to limited speed of light?

Explain how do you reconcile the concept of physical reality with symmetry principle in special relativity?

Comment: they are physically real.

Comment: OK- if that is so how can all inertial frames be equivalent? If two rods are moving relative to each other than each should be shorter than the other one? What kind or "reality" depends on the point of view?

Comment: "What kind or "reality" depends on the point of view?": Ours

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an observer will deduce in his frame that the length of a moving rod (which has a length l in the rest frame of the rod) has shortened by a factor of 1/gamma (gamma=Lorentz factor). So in his frame it has a length 1/gamma.

This does not necessarily mean he **sees** it like that, arising from the practicalities of how we see objects moving at the speed of light (eg light emitted from further away takes longer to reach eyes, so a moving perpendicular line will appear curved). This is not an effect arising from relativity though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52258/discussion-on-answer-by-jem-bishop-relativistic-effects-real).  Participants in the chat are kindly reminded to [be nice](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).